# Is there a specific armor set fitting an archer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know i need light armor for my sneaking and movement, but what specific set and enchantments would fit best?

Comment: @ChargingPun [Archery](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery) is a [Combat](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Combat) skill, not a [Stealth](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stealth) skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most generic, directly useful enchant for an archer is, obviously, the [Fortify Archery](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Archery) effect.

Some unique armor includes:

- [Gauntlets of the Old Gods](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gauntlets_of_the_Old_Gods#Gauntlets_of_the_Old_Gods),
- All varieties of the [Shrouded Cowl](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shrouded_Cowl#Shrouded_Cowl), especially the [Ancient](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancient_Shrouded_Cowl),
- [Linwe's hood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Linwe%27s_Hood), which also add 15% damage to bows,
- The Dragon Mask [Krosis](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Krosis_%28item%29) reinforce it to 20%.

After you got these, you still need to cover you feet and torso. These pieces cannot be enchanted with Forty Archery, but other things can be useful:

- [Muffle](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle_%28effect%29) boots (you can find this, eg. on the shrouded armor),
- [Fortify Sneak](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Sneak) boots (or hood) (Boots of the Old Good or Linwe's boots have it),
- [Fortify Stamina](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Stamina) on armor,
- [Fortify Light Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Light_Armor),
- You can also use some elemental resistance, depending on your Ring and Amulet or special abilities (resist fire if you are a vampire, for example)

You can of course posses different set of armor, depending on the circumstances. I always like to keep an [Thieves Guild Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_Armor#Thieves_Guild_Armor) on me for when I am over my carry limit, and a pair of gloves with a stabbing multiplier.

Comment: If you have a good enough enchanting skill or like to use the "fortify restoration loop", applying your own Fortify Archery to high-level light armor is always the best way to go. Keeping around multiple sets of armor for different circumstances is also a good idea to keep in mind.